# Odoo : Computed fields, don't update in some case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have a computed field, that has to be updated when a field is updated.
So I use `@api.depends('field1')` and link the function

```
field_to_compute: fields.integer(compute='the_function' store=True)
```

It works fine.

But know I'd like to update it when `field1` take value `A` and to remain the same when `field1` take the value `B`. But the old value of `field_to_compute` was imported from a database and wasn't computed.

So I have two problems:

- How can I allow the user to set the value himself. (I can modify it,
  but when I create a new member, it will be computed and only after
  the first save I can modify it in UI)
- How can I make something like:

  ```
  @api.depends('field1')
  def the_function(self): 
       value = self.field1
       if value == A:
           field_to_compute = 123123
       elif value == B: 
           field_to_compute = stored_field_to_compute #field_to_compute
  ```

  keep the same value as the one stored before

**EDIT (example):**

I'm in a res.partner in the current model, inheriting of res.partner.
I've a field in it :

```
'model_state': field.char(compute='compute_type', string = 'Demand', store=True, readonly=True)
```

In a second res.partner inheriting of res.partner too, in an other module, I have 2 fields : `grade` and  `status`, respectively an int, and a many2one. Computing the same compute_type as model_state, the same way.

I also in this res.partner, have a one2many field : `link_ids`

So my function is :

```
@api.depends('link_ids.type', 'link_ids.result')
def compute_type(self):
    for record in self:
       if self.link_ids:
           if self.link_ids.result == 'A':
               if self.link_ids.type == 'type1':
                   record.model_state = 'Mytext'
                   record.grade = 15
                   record.state = 1 #this is an id
               elif self.link_ids.result == 'B':
                   record.model_state = 'MySecondText'
                   record.state = 2 #this is an id
```

I won't put everything because it's like 25 elif (not all about the same if etc etc) so it wouldn't be pertinent. I checked a lot of time if nothing was modifying record.grade if nothing is done on it, in else or dunno, but it's just being emptied.

Basically, simplified, I'd like to do something if the result is "OK" to a vote. And change the id of the state to "accepted", give a text (like a title), and give him a better grade, and if it's not, he have an id of the state "denied", give an other text, and keep the same grade as he has actually.

Comment: How can you guess `self.link_ids.result` the result from one2many like this ? where as link_ids may contains multiple records so there may be multiple results. And hope there is no mistake in code here is typo in depends actually it's `@api.depends(...)`

Comment: primary key, to one res_partner you can only make one demand. It's just in order to have acces to my res_partner in the tree view and select one of them (i'm in an editable tree view). So, when in res_partner I ask for links_ids, it will find the tuple where he is and look at the values. I tried a lot and it always did what I expected, except for the field which must not change

(I needed to select one res.partner in my model and the many2one view is pretty usefull for that)

Comment: About the typo, I added the 's', it only was a typo in my post, not in the code

Comment: if i'm not wrong the `self.link_ids.field_x == 'foobar'` comparisons will give you a singleton error with more than one entry in link_ids.

Comment: Yes it does, but it was supposed to, it was supposed to be only one link_ids per res_partner. Finally, client changed his mind, any idea about how to make a one2one relation? (In order to have no singleton error anymore), if I change my link_ids in a many2one, i'll have a many2one in res_partner, and a many2one in my model. Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a prefetch by yourself (field_to_compute has to be stored):

```python
@api.multi
@api.depends('field_x')
def _compute_field_to_compute(self):
    # prefetch
    data = {d['id']: d['field_to_compute']
            for d in self.read(['field_to_compute'])}
    for record in self:
        if record.field_x == '123456':
            record.field_to_compute = '654321'
        else:
            record.field_to_compute = data.get(record.id, 'default')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll try as soon as I can!

Will this keep my res_partner computed fields up even after I'll remove the demand? (@api.depends refer to fields in demand, and the computed field is in res_partner, so when I remove the demand every fields computed were removed.

Comment: I get this error, for record._origin record.origin, and self._origin

record.freemason_grade = record._origin.freemason_grade
AttributeError: 'res.partner' object has no attribute '_origin'

(Under odoo 8)

About the second option, I need to store two different fields, I just have to change d['id'] to d['di'] for the second one for exemple?

Comment: I will edit my anwser. The _origin solution could only be used within onchanges. And to your second question: you can just use dictionaries within the dictionary. Just replace `d['field_to_compute']` with `{'stored_field_1':d['stored_field_1'], 'stored_field_2': d['stored_field_2']}` and use it like `record.stored_field_1 = data.get(record.id, {}).get('stored_field_1', 'default')`

Comment: Thank you, does the for inside `data` will be {'stored_field_1', 'stored_field_2'} ?

Comment: Model.read will return a list of dictionaries like: `[{'id': 1, 'field_1': 'foo', 'field_n': 'bar'},{'id': 2, 'field_1': 'bar', 'field_2': 'foo'}]`

Comment: Thank you it worked, just in time for the demo! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

if the value is B just don't do anything... or better: set the field value only when needed. Something like:

```
def _compute_foo(self):
    for item in self:
        if item.other_field != B:
             item.foo = 'newvalue'
```

I think you problem is that you are not setting the value as you should do for computed fields (see `item.foo = 'newvalue'`).

Take a look at [official docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html).

Comment: When I don't set any value to the field, it become empty (NULL)
Edit : I think it try to compute anyway since it's a computed field, but it see no value given, so it simply don't input any value.. Even if it is store=True

Answer (score 1):

You should try following,

```
@api.onchange('field1')
def function(self):
    field_value = self.field_to_compute
    if self.field1 == A:
        field_value = 123123
    self.field_to_compute = field_value
```

Comment: I just tried,  it works if the value is A, it will give 123123.
But if the value is B it's still empty, even if it wasn't.
But I'm using api.depends since I modify value from 2 different module.
It seams that when it call the compute, it first empty the fields that will be computed and then run the function.

Maybe I'll have to create a fields which store the actual state of the field

Comment: Just to precise, I check before and after the modification in the database with phppgadmin and it is NULL after.

Comment: Can you give me bit more idea what you want to achieve, aim with example data ?

Comment: I edited so you can see it clearly. Thanks for taking some time for my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
@api.onchange('field1')
def function(self)
     if value == A:
         field_to_compute = 123123
     elif value == B: 
         field_to_compute = stored_field_to_compute #field_to_compute keep the same value as the one stored before
```

Answer (score 0):

For the computed fields that needs to save its value on DB table, we use the "@api..depends('field_attributes')" decorator, that when there were a change made to the defined fields attributes, it will trigger to execute the Function.

For the computed fields that don't need to have saved its value on DB table, we do not need anymore this "@api..depends('field_attributes')", Reloading the form would serve as a trigger for the function's execution. But the disadvantage for this is, we won't be able to search a data from this certain field.